# AngularJs optional transclude

Tags: angularjs, directive

I've written a directive without the transclude option.

But now it would be nice when I could activate the transclude function/option when calling the directive with another attribute or something else if possible.

If that's not possible the only Way I see is, to copy the directive and add the Transclude in the second one, but then I've doubled my code whtat I'm not willing to do.

any Ideas how to optionally activate the transclude in Angular 1.2.x

Edit:

alternate problem is also that I need to set the ng-transclude in my directive Template because its a big one and only a few rows can be replaced by the transclusion content.

Comment: You could just use `ng-if` or something in your template

Comment: thats not what I need, I need the transclude to replace the content with new content I don't know yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could conditionally modify a template to include `ng-transclude` in the `compile:` function.

```
.directive('foo', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'foo.html',
    compile: function (element, attrs) {
      if (attrs.bar !== undefined) {
        element.find('.may-transclude-here')
          .attr('ng-transclude', '');
      }

      return function postLink(scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
        scope.listEntries = ['apple', 'banana', 'tomato'];
      };
    }
  }
})
```

and a html template:

```
<div class="foo">
  <h4>Directive title</h4>
  <div class="may-transclude-here" ng-repeat="item in listEntries">
    Original content: {{item}}
  </div>
  <span>blah blah blah</span>
</div>
```

but contents that are transcluded via `ng-transclude` will not bind with a scope of each item created by `ng-repeat`. In case you also need the binding, here is the modified version of `ng-transclude` that do the correct scope binding.

```
.directive('myTransclude', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers, transcludeFn) {
      transcludeFn(scope, function(nodes) {
        element.empty();
        element.append(nodes);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

**Plunker example:** http://plnkr.co/edit/8lncowJ7jdbN0DEowdxP?p=preview

hope this helps.

Comment: I've editet my Question - your solution is a cool Idea but doesn't solve my Problem because I need to set the ng-transclude tag in my Template that I know where to Replace the Content.

Comment: I've edited the answer and plunker. If you wouldn't mind using something other than `ng-transclude` to mark where the transcluded content should be placed, it should works.

Comment: hi, I've tried the link Version - that works fine until :-) --> I have an ng-repeat in the same element where my "class='may-transclude-here'" is, then its not getting transcluded "<li class="may-transclude-here" ng-repeat="item in listEntries"> ..."

Comment: Give it another try, I have edited the answer with trasclutions inside `ng-repeat`.